# Can I use Apple magic mouse with glove?

Tags: mouse, multi-touch

For some reasons, I need to use Apple Magic Mouse with glove which is not too thick but just like white cotton gloves that tech review youtubers wear.

When I touch my iPhone, iPad, or Macbook with the glove, somehow works if I push it with pressure to touch but it's true that it's not easy to touch.

However, when I touch my Airpods Pro 2nd generation to volume up and down with my glove, it works well.

Maybe its touch sensor is more sensitive than other devices.

Will the Magic Mouse work as well as the AirPods do?

Answer (score 1):

The mouse is a capacitive touch, so you need to choose a thinner glove material or one that’s designed for capacitive touch screens. Many of these exist on the market for outdoor / cold weather use, but I’m not aware of an indoor version that I can recommend.

Here is what might be suitable to consider: [Sibba Touch Screen Moisturizing Gloves](https://a.co/d/4A9fSEK)

Go with a (very if possible) thin glove for now is my advice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I’ll take a look at the glove you recommended.